# navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices does not return any audioinput devices on iOS Safari (13.2.3)

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, getusermedia, mediadevices

I am trying to record audio on iOS Safari (13.2.3), but Safari is not providing access to the microphone. When I call `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices`, it only returns a single `MediaDeviceInfo` (kind: `videoinput`)

I read elsewhere to call `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})` first, but that gives an Invalid constraint error. `getSupportedConstraints` does not show that audio/video are valid options (only `aspectRatio, deviceId, echoCancellation, facingMode, frameRate, groupId, height, sampleRate, sampleSize, volume, width`).

This is on an ipod touch 7th edition, which definitely has a microphone; eg. Siri can hear me. I'm not sure why the microphone isn't showing up for Safari, while the camera is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like the iPod Touch (7th edition; 2019) supports microphone-only access in Safari.

When I tested on iPhones using the same iOS version (13.2.3), the code worked flawlessly, even when the iPhones did not have SIM cards. (Tested both on an iPhone 7 and iPhone 8).